# Adding a Relationship in olap Cube

Tags: olap, multidimensional-array, dimensions, ssas, olap-cube

Is possible to join a dimension to an OLAP cube using fields that do not have a foreign-key relationship in the underlying relational DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. It is called logical relationship and is defined in DSV - data source view. Just drag a many side field (logical FK) from one table to logical PK field of another table.

Comment: I don't think you even need to define the logical keys.  In the Dimension Usage tab just pick the dimension attribute you want to join on (which is generally the dimension key) and you can choose any of the columns in the measure group to join on.